# Can we leverage Spark's CBO (Cost Based Optimizer) with native parquet or in-memory dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, cbo

Say i want to join 3 tables A,B,C with inner join and C being very small.

```
#DUMMY EXAMPLE with IN-MEMORY table, but same issue if load table using spark.read.parquet("")
var A = (1 to 1000000).toSeq.toDF("A")
var B = (1 to 1000000).toSeq.toDF("B")
var C = (1 to 10).toSeq.toDF("C")
```

And i have no control of which order the join is brought to me :

```
CASE1 = A.join(B,expr("A=B"),"inner").join(C,expr("A=C"),"inner")
CASE2 = A.join(C,expr("A=C"),"inner").join(B,expr("A=B"),"inner")
```

Running both show CASE1 run 30-40% slower than CASE2.

So the question is: how to leverage Spark's CBO to automatically translate CASE1 as CASE2 for in-memory table or table loaded from Spark's parquet reader?

I have tried doing :

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.cbo.enabled", "true")
A.createOrReplaceTempView("A")
spark.sql("ANALYZE TABLE A COMPUTE STATISTICS")
```

but this throws :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'a' not found in database 'default'
```

Any other way to activate CBO without having to save the table in Hive?

---

**Annex:**

1. Even with spark.conf.set("spark.sql.cbo.enabled", "true") there is no cost estimation shown in the SparkWebUI
2. Showing CASE1.explain != CASE2.explain

CASE1.explain

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(5) SortMergeJoin [A#3], [C#13], Inner
:- *(3) SortMergeJoin [A#3], [B#8], Inner
:  :- *(1) Sort [A#3 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(A#3, 200)
:  :     +- LocalTableScan [A#3]
:  +- *(2) Sort [B#8 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     +- Exchange hashpartitioning(B#8, 200)
:        +- LocalTableScan [B#8]
+- *(4) Sort [C#13 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(C#13, 200)
      +- LocalTableScan [C#13]
```

CASE2.explain

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(5) SortMergeJoin [A#3], [B#8], Inner
:- *(3) SortMergeJoin [A#3], [C#13], Inner
:  :- *(1) Sort [A#3 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(A#3, 200)
:  :     +- LocalTableScan [A#3]
:  +- *(2) Sort [C#13 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     +- Exchange hashpartitioning(C#13, 200)
:        +- LocalTableScan [C#13]
+- *(4) Sort [B#8 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(B#8, 200)
      +- LocalTableScan [B#8]
```

Comment: It works against persisted data, not in memory data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, short answer is that this is not possible.

This https://databricks.com/blog/2017/08/31/cost-based-optimizer-in-apache-spark-2-2.html provides an excellent overview of what is possible and the point on persisted data stores.